# Mostrar lista de los servicios que tiene y no tiene de una ID

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

estoy mostrando los servicios que tiene un vivivienda, para ello tengo 3 tablas, (vivienda, servicio, vivienda_servicio)

**vivienda -->** son todos los datos de la vivienda, su identificador es = vivienda_id
**servicio -->** aquí tengo una lista con los servicios, columnas = servicio_id , nombre 
**vivienda_servicio -->** aquí los servicios de los que dispone cada vivienda = vivienda_vivienda_id , servicio_servicio_id

Luego estoy haciendo una query para que me muestre todos los servicios que hay en la tabla servicio que corresponde a la `id` de la vivienda que estoy visualizando, los servicios que esa vivienda si que tiene que salen de la tabla `vivienda_servicio` me los muestra con un check en verde y también muestra los que no tiene con un ckeck en rojo.

Os muestro el código:

```
<?php
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ser.servicio_id, ser.nombre, vis.vivienda_vivienda_id, vis.servicio_servicio_id
    FROM servicio AS ser, vivienda_servicio AS vis
    WHERE vis.vivienda_vivienda_id =" .$_GET['ID']);
    foreach ($results as $s)
    $ss = $s['nombre'];{
    ?>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-xl-3 margChecks">
      <h3><?php echo $ss ?></h3>

      <?php
      $viviendaServicio = find($s['servicio_id']);

      if (isset($viviendaServicio])) {
        echo "<i class=\"fas fa-check-circle fastcheck corrigeCheck\"></i>";
      }else{
        echo "<i class=\"fas fa-times-circle fastcheck2\"></i>";
      }
      ?>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Me devuelve la pantalla en blanco, esta bien hecho el código???

Comment: Si te devuelve la pantalla en blanco es evidente que no está bien hecho. Usa `var_dump` para comprobar todas las variables, por ejemplo: `var_dump($results);` para ver si la consulta trae datos. Prueba también `$viviendaServicio` luego de la llamada a `find`, etc. Son comprobaciones rutinarias en un código  ¿no? Luego, tu consulta es vulnerable, pero eso no necesariamente es motivo de fallo, pero sí un problema de seguridad ya que te pueden inyectar código dañino por medio de ella, pero ese es otro tema, propongo que pongas en agenda una lectura sobre *inyección SQL*.

Comment: Ahora ya desconecte el pc para descansar, mañana revisare con el vardump, era por si habia algo visible para que no funcionara que yo no veo

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano he comprobado con var_dump y me sigue saliendo en blanco la pantalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Primero consultamos todos los servicios sin condiciones.

```
    $myID = $_GET['ID'];
    $servicios = $mysqli->query("SELECT ser.servicio_id, ser.nombre
    FROM servicio AS ser");
    foreach ($servicios as $s){
```

Después comprobamos si esa `$myID`esta en la tabla de vivienda_servicio, si es asi me muestra el check verde y por lo contrario el rojo.

```
$serv_id = $s['servicio_id'];
      $viviendaServicio = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vivienda_servicio WHERE vivienda_vivienda_id = $myID AND servicio_servicio_id = $serv_id");
      $viv = $viviendaServicio->fetch_array();
      if (isset($viv)) {
        echo "<i class=\"fas fa-check-circle fastcheck corrigeCheck\"></i>";
      }else{
        echo "<i class=\"fas fa-times-circle fastcheck2\"></i>";
      }
```